# SRP processing file line-by-line

Tags: c#, sql-server, single-responsibility

I'm writing a class that read lines from a file, process them, store them in an accumulator and when it reaches a threshold bulk inserts in a SqlServer database. Like this:

```
class FooImporterToSqlServer
{
    private string ConnectionString { get;} //initilized via constuctor
    private AccumulatorCollection Accumulators { get;} //initilized via constuctor
    private FooProcessor Processor { get;} //initilized via constuctor
    private int LastHierarchyId { get; set;} //initilized via constuctor, starts at 0

    public void Import(string path)
    {
        var lines = File.ReadAllLines(path);
        foreach(var line in lines)
        {
            var processedLine = Processor.Process(line, ref LastHierarchyId);
            Accumulators.Add(processedLine);
            if(Accumulators.HaveAnyFull())
                UnloadAccumulators();
        }
    }

    private void UnloadAccumulator()
    {
        var fullAccumulators = Accumulators.GetFullAccumulators();
        foreach(var fullAccumulator in fullAccumulators)
        {
            //bulk insert black magic
        }
    }
}
```

But I can't help but fell I'm breaking single responsibility with the `FooImporterToSqlServer` class. It does too much: it reads the file, uses the accumulator and then inserts in the database.
But I also don't know how to separate these concerns in this case where I need to stop he process halfway. Specially maintaining state between different insertions. Normally there would be something like `FooReaderToMemory` then `FooInsertToSqlServer` but in this case they're one in the same. Any ideas on how can I refactor process like this to not break SRP?

EDIT: for clarification, I can't read, process and then import the file because the processed lines are too much to hold in memory all at once.

Please feel free to note anything else wrong with the example I provided!

Comment: `I can't read, process and then import the file because the processed lines are too much to hold in memory all at once.` -- Use a Stream, or some other similar mechanism that doesn't require you to read the file at once and doesn't violate SRP.

Comment: This line.... var lines = File.ReadAllLines(path); will doom you to out of memory exceptions with larger files.  To avoid this, read the file one line at a time and then process and push into a dbwriter queue that auto flushes when it reaches your threshold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here goes my suggestion in the following code. I'm trying to solve the problems below:

- If I need to change the way of extracting the data (currently is from a file), I want to change only one class (no problem if additional class needs to be created);
- If I need to change the database or way of importing the data, I want to change only one class (no problem if additional class needs to be created);
- If I want to change the overall process (by adding or changing steps) I want change only one class;

  ```
  class FooImporter
  {
      private IFooImporter Importer { get;} //no more connection string; now the importer is injected (doesn't matter how it imports)

      private AccumulatorCollection Accumulators { get;} //initilized via constuctor
      private FooProcessor Processor { get;} //initilized via constuctor
      private IFooExtractor Extractor {get;} //this class does not open files anymore, this is done by the extractor injected
      private int LastHierarchyId { get; set;} //initilized via constuctor, starts at 0

      public void Import() //now the path is private detail of the Extractor injected
      {
          using (Extractor.BeginExtract())
          {
              while (Extractor.HasNext())
              {
                  var line = Extractor.GetNext();
                  var processedLine = Processor.Process(line, ref LastHierarchyId);
                  Accumulators.Add(processedLine);
                  if(Accumulators.HaveAnyFull())
                      UnloadAccumulators();
              }
          }
      }

      private void UnloadAccumulator()
      {
          var fullAccumulators = Accumulators.GetFullAccumulators();
          foreach(var fullAccumulator in fullAccumulators)
          {
              Importer.Import(fullAcumulator);
          }
      }
  }

  class SqlServerFooImporter : IFooImporter  //You could have different importers
  {
      private string ConnectionString { get;} //initilized via constuctor

      private void Import(Accumulator fullAcumulator)
      {
          //bulk insert black magic
      }
  }
  ```

To summarize: your example code shows a class that might have multiple reasons to change. Therefore I suggested a design on which each class has one reasons to have its code changed; also for new features you implement new classes and inject them in the importer (just like you're already doing, but not for all steps of the process).

Comment: This answer is pretty useless as-is, you should provide some explanation of what changes you made, and why those changes are appropriate.

Comment: Edited my answer to explain better what I'm suggesting.

Answer (score 5):

> But I can't help but fell I'm breaking encapsulation with the FooImporterToSqlServer class. It does too much: it reads the file, uses the accumulator and then inserts in the database.

Encapsulation? That's not an encapsulation concern. Doing to much is a Single Responsibility Principle concern. The encapsulation concern comes from publicly accessible getters.  Those would expose your state. That would leave me wondering what code, that isn't even mentioned by this class, has a need to use your ConnectionString, Accumulators, Processor, and LastHierarchyId?

As for following the Single Responsibility Principle, you are. The single responsibility of the `FooImporterToSqlServer` is to import files. I don't expect to find anything in here that doesn't help it do that.

Comment: I'm sorry, confused this one, I will edit. Nothing besides this class uses ConnectionString, Accumulators and Processor. LastHierarchyId is a db field that is used for fks. I added some clarification in the answers as well.

Comment: None of the properties here are marked as public (the default for C# here would be private), so I'm not sure there is any problem with encapsulation.  Possibly clarity if you aren't familiar with default accessibility levels in C#, but not encapsulation.

Comment: Oh, I just omitted them for this snippet, sorry. I'm familiar with C#'s default accessibility. What I really meant in this question (thanks for helping me formulate that) is how can I refactor this to not break the SRP considering I have to insert things to db halfway through the process. Maybe it wasn't such a great question after all, but since I comes up pretty frequently with my code I thought it wouldn't hurt to ask. Thanks for clarification on naming, though!

Answer (score 1):

As @CandiedOrange pointed out, I do not see you are breaking SRP here. You have a class for processing data, class for accumulating data, and a class for storing the data to the database. Each class does its own work. The only way you could decouple it more would be to have a class that would do the file parsing, and that class would encapsulate the above four classes, but in this case, I think it would be an overkill.

I will, though, address the paragraph below:

> EDIT: for clarification, I can't read, process and then import the file because the processed lines are too much to hold in memory all at once.

One way to go around that problem is the one you implemented. The other one would be to implement a consumer-producer pattern, where one thread would populate the collection of lines, and the other one would empty it while importing that data into the database. That way, the buffer would 'breathe', and the memory consumption would be reduced.

The approach you took could have better performance, though, if you are using some bulk import techniques. With your approach, there would be less round-trips to the database.